# Request to Generate OTP is Failing. Error Says "Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN reciever"

Tags: mongodb, express, backend

```
`Terminal : DB Connected
```

My Backend Js code :

DB Connected Successfully
Email id is :  reciever2050@gmail.com
OTP Generated :  306218
Promise {  }
Error occured while sending mails :  Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN reciever
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookupall [as oncomplete] (node:dns:118:26) {
errno: -3001,
code: 'EDNS',
syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
hostname: 'reciever',
command: '
}

```
exports.sendOTP = async (req, res) => {
    try{
    // Fetch Email from body and verify
    const {email} = req.body;
    console.log("Email id is : ", email);
    const checkUser = await User.findOne({email});
    
    // If user with that mail Id already exists
    if(checkUser){
        return res.status(401).json({
            success: false,
            messages: "User already exists"
        })
    }

    // Generate OTP
    var otp = otpGenerator.generate(6, {
        upperCaseAlphabets: false,
        lowerCaseAlphabets: false,
        specialChars: false,
    })
    console.log("OTP Generated : ", otp)

    // Verify OTP
    const result = await OTP.findOne({otp: otp})

    // Keep generating a new OTP until you find a unique OTP
    // This is bad practice as you are needing to generate new
    // OTPS again and again and put them in the DB
    while(result){
        otp = otpGenerator.generate(6, {
            upperCaseAlphabets: false,
            lowerCaseAlphabets: false,
            specialChars: false
        })
        result = await OTP.findOne({otp: otp})
    }

    const otpPayload = {email, otp};
    
    // DB Entry for OTP
    const otpBody = await OTP.create(otpPayload)
    console.log(otpBody);

    res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        message: 'OTP Sent successfully',
        otp
    })
 }
 catch(error){
    return res.status(500).json({
        success: false,
        messages: `Complete Failure : ${error.message}`, 
        // messages: error.message,
    })
 }
```

I was expecting for an OTP to be generated and it being Stored in the DB. It was Created but
the app crashed after that Stating a pending promise and the following errors. How can I fix      this ?`